# iOS 13.5 Swift - APNS Push notifications not receiving in production - No firebase

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have configured Amazons APNS in my app and it was working fine couple of weeks back. But now stopped working. I never used any Dev environment/certificates in my app. Device token is generated and receiving push notifications when the Build mode is "Debug". But when i push the same build with "Release" mode to push app into Test flight, push notifications are not receiving and also the Device token is not generated in this release mode. Am i Doing anything wrong?
I believe there shouldn't be any environment problem as I am not using any dev env/certificates and directly using the prod certificate here. Am i confused here? should i change something in Certificates? Any help is greatly appreciated